# Determining Statement Truth or Falsity

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

I'm learning how to determine the truth value of statements and I want to make sure that i'm understanding and answering the questions correctly.  I'm struggling with determining if i'm reading the statements correctly.  I'm reading $\forall$x $\exists$y as "for all x there exists a y".  Is this correct?  Are my answers correct?  (my answers are the italics and the problem sets are to the left)

**Domain: $\mathbb R$ (all real numbers)**

a) ∀x∃y(x^2 = y) *= True (for any x^2 there is a y that exists)*

b) ∀x∃y(x = y^2) *= False (x is negative no real number can be negative^2*

c) ∃x∀y(xy=0) *= True (x = 0 all y will create product of 0)*

d) ∀x(x≠0 → ∃y(xy=1)) *= True (x != 0 makes the statement valid in the domain of all real numbers)*

e) ∃x∀y(y≠0 → xy=1) *= False (no single x value that satisfies equation for all y*

f) ∃x∃y(x+2y=2 ∧ 2x+4y=5) *= False (doubling value through doubling variable coefficients without doubling sum value)*

g) ∀x∃y(x+y=2 ∧ 2x−y=1) *= False (really unsure about this one)*

Comment: Not "there is a y that exists" but "there is a y" **or** "exists a y".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA got it.  That makes more sense "exists a y".  Do my answers conform with that logic?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA and thank you for your help!

Comment: g) consider it as a system of equations; adding them we get : $3x=3$ that is not true for every $x$. Proof: consider $x=2$; then we must have some $y$ such that $2+y=2$ and $4-y=1$, which is impossible. Conclusion: *FALSE*.

Comment: Other than slight roughness in the wording (which I expect will improve as you read more mathematics), the thinking appears to be good. For g), you just need one counterexample. An easy one is $x=0.$ (In fact you only needed one counterexample for b), although you found infinitely many.)

Comment: Thank you gents!  Just starting out with this area and am very excited to keep progressing forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a) True$

$b) False$

$c) True$

$d) True$

$e) False$

$f) False$

$g) False$

Basically you got them all right. Regarding $g)$, you can either find an $x$ for which the statement isn't true or you solve the equation, obtaining specific (static, say) values for $x$ and $y$, thus proving it's falsity.